# File.rename not working on Windows

Tags: ruby

Here's the code:

```
files = Dir.glob("*")
files.each do |file|
 if File.extname(file) == ".pdf"    
   format = file.split(".pdf")
   format = format.join("").split(" ")
   format[0] = format[0].gsub(".","/")
   format[0] << "_"
   format[0].prepend("_")
   format[-1] << ".pdf"
   format = format.join("")
   puts "Changed #{file} to #{format}"
   File.rename(file,format)
 end
end
```

It is running from the same directory as the files. I have tried giving the `File.rename` parameters absolute paths as well, by appending the result of `Dir.pwd` to them. Code isn't very clean as it was something I whipped up real quick, please excuse that.

I get the following error:

```
Changed 05.01.14 Mid-Day 1.pdf to _05/01/14_Mid-Day1.pdf
script.rb:12:in `rename': No such file or directory - (05.01.14 Mid-Day 1.pdf, _05/01/14_Mid-Day1.pdf) (Errno::ENOENT)
        from script.rb:12:in `block in <main>'
        from script.rb:2:in `each'
        from script.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

If I call `File.exists?(file)` it comes back as true. I'm thoroughly confused on why this doesn't work.

I am on running this on Windows.

Comment: `format.join("")` is better written `format.join`. Consider writing `gsub(".","/")` as `tr('.', '/')` as it's faster. And, instead of repeatedly assigning to `format[0]`, assign that value to a separate value, then, when you're done, assign back to `format[0]`. It's less confusing and a tiny bit faster.

Comment: And, it'd greatly help, when you're asking for help, if you'd clearly supply some input data, such as the paths you're seeing. As is we get to make it up based on the error, which hardly helps us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory structure *_05/01* does not seem to exist. You need to create the directories first with `FileUtils.mkdir_p` before being able to move the file there.

Comment: .....And I just realized my issue. I must have had a brain fart when I decided to put slashes in the filename. Thanks for making that obvious for me haha.

Comment: Ruby treats paths on windows with forward slashes as well, which is why your script tries to move the file to the subdirectories.

Comment: "`Ruby treats paths on windows with forward slashes as well`" is [documented in the IO class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html). In other words, treat all file paths as if they were Linux and Ruby will be happy. Of course this doesn't apply to URLs, but that's a different can of worms.